# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 error : "Property '_value' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'."

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I try to get a value in a form builder and I have this error :

[image]

And in my bowser :

[image]

I don't undersand beacause my console.log works !

There is my code :

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'address',
  templateUrl: 'address-component.html'
})

export class AddressComponentPage {
  @Input('group')
  public addressForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.addressForm._value.type);
  }
}
```

I want to get my "type" value to use it for generate form field dynamically with different type of field.

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html

Comment: Don't you need to import and implement ngonit?

Comment: Done, my function now implements OnInit